# How can I prevent TfidfVectorizer to get numbers as vocabulary

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use TfidfVectorizer like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, min_df=200)
xs['train'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs['train'])
xs['test'] = vectorizer.transform(docs['test']).toarray()
```

But when inspecting `vectorizer.vocabulary_` I've noticed that it learns pure number features:

```
[(u'00', 0), (u'000', 1), (u'0000', 2), (u'00000', 3), (u'000000', 4)
```

I don't want this. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could define the `token_pattern` when initing the vectorizer. The default one is `u'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'` (the `(?u)` part is just turning the `re.UNICODE` flag on). Could fiddle with that until you get what you need.

Something like:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words,
                             min_df=200,
                             token_pattern=u'(?u)\b\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*\b')
```

---

Another option (if the fact that numbers appear in your samples matter) is to mask all the numbers before vectorizing.

```
re.sub('\b[0-9][0-9.,-]*\b', 'NUMBER-SPECIAL-TOKEN', sample)
```

This way numbers will hit the same spot in your vectorizer's vocabulary and you won't completely ignore them either.

Comment: the first way is going to ignore unicode characters also. for example `ồ`